# Как настроить стадию сделки Bitrix API

Tags: python, api, битрикс

Как мне найти идентификатор нужной стадии сделки? В какое поле нужно его передавать?
Стадия создаётся в стадии "обращение", а нужно новый заказ (временный).
[image: Вот так создаётся по дефолту]

[image: А вот так должно быть (нижняя сделка)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стадия сделки хранится в `STAGE_ID`.

Список стадий можно получить с помощью `crm.status.list` (https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/crm/auxiliary/status/crm_status_list.php)

с фильтром `filter: { "ENTITY_ID": "STATUS" }`